# Using getRESTAPISessionKey from Lightning Container

Tags: lightning-aura-components, rest-api

Does anyone know how to properly call into RESTApi using LCC.getRESTAPISessionKey()?

For example from https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/container_npm_getrestapisessionkey.htm

```
componentDidMount() {
  let sid = LCC.getRESTAPISessionKey();
  let conn = new JSForce.Connection({accessToken: sid});
  conn.query("SELECT Id, Name from Account LIMIT 50", this.handleAccountQueryResponse);
}
```

doesn't work. I believe the CORS is set properly.I get the following error

INVALID_SESSION_ID: This session is not valid for use with the REST API

What is the proper usage of LCC.getRESTAPISessionKey()?

Comment: Are you writing a container app? If not, this method is not for you.

Comment: Yes I am writing a container app.

Answer (score 0):

API Access for  Apps has been revoked as of winter 18.

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring18/release-notes/rn_lc_api_revert_cruc.htm